# Установка курсора на ссылку при открытии, обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Не получается написать скрипт на javascript, чтобы после обновления страницы или входа на страницу, курсор мыши автоматически позиционировался на нужную ссылку, например, "вперед".

Comment: а может пусть пользователь сам решит, где его курсору быть?

Comment: курсором нельзя управлять... Можно только фокусом, что не одно и тоже...

Comment: Что означает фокусом? Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но мне кажется надо писать свой браузер и через API ОС ставить туда куда надо...